# PostgreSQL duplicate key value violates unique constraint while using on conflict do nothing on insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, plpgsql

Table def:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS lazy_product_stock_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE "public"."lazy_product_stock" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('lazy_product_stock_id_seq'::regclass),
    "product_id" int4,
    "hold" int4 DEFAULT 0,
    "quantity" int4 DEFAULT 0,
    "warehouse_id" int4,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lazy_product_stock_pkey ON public.lazy_product_stock USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX lazy_product_stock_product_id_idx ON public.lazy_product_stock USING btree (product_id)
CREATE INDEX lazy_product_stock_warehouse_id_idx ON public.lazy_product_stock USING btree (warehouse_id)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "lazy_product_stock_comb_idx2" ON "public"."lazy_product_stock" USING BTREE ("product_id","warehouse_id");
```

I have a function that inserts new rows into the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_lazystock_i_f(_product_id int4, site_id int4) RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare
warehouse record;
BEGIN
FOR warehouse IN select id from warehouse where siteid = site_id LOOP
    insert into lazy_product_stock (product_id, warehouse_id) VALUES (_product_id, warehouse.id) ON CONFLICT (product_id,warehouse_id) DO NOTHING;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It fails with

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lazy_product_stock_comb_idx2"
```

the index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "lazy_product_stock_comb_idx2" ON "public"."lazy_product_stock" USING BTREE ("product_id","warehouse_id");
```

Although running the relevant insert on its own with duplicate values it has no problem with it.

```
insert into lazy_product_stock (product_id, warehouse_id) VALUES (123, 1234) ON CONFLICT (product_id,warehouse_id) DO NOTHING;

Query 1 OK: INSERT 0 0, 0 rows affected
```

I can't understand what seems to be the the difference between the function and the single statement?

This also works without a problem:

```
do $$
declare
warehouse record;
begin
    FOR warehouse IN select id from warehouse where siteid = 123 LOOP
    insert into lazy_product_stock (product_id, warehouse_id) VALUES (12345, warehouse.id) ON CONFLICT (product_id,warehouse_id) DO NOTHING;
END LOOP;
end; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

same error with

```
insert into lazy_product_stock (product_id, warehouse_id)
    select _product_id, warehouse.id
    from warehouse where siteid = site_id
    on conflict (product_id, warehouse_id) do nothing;
```

I am using Postgresql 12.3

Comment: Edit your question and show the definition of the table.  I suspect you have other unique constraints on it.

Comment: updated the question to include the table definition

Comment: Unrelated, but: the loop is completely unnecessary and will only make things a lot slower

Comment: I can't reproduce that: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f36fecb50aba3bcdb2daeb001a2da2b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had 2 such functions trigerring on the same logic which caused the problem. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 2):

Why use a loop for this?  How about:

```
insert into lazy_product_stock (product_id, warehouse_id)
    select _product_id, w.id
    from warehouse where siteid = site_id
    on conflict (product_id, warehouse_id) do nothing;
```

Comment: same error when using your insert duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lazy_product_stock_comb_idx2"

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you don't specify a target?

```
insert into lazy_product_stock (product_id, warehouse_id)
select _product_id, warehouse.id
from warehouse 
where siteid = site_id
on conflict do nothing;
```

`do nothing` is the one and only conflict action that does not require specifying a target, which makes this workaround possible here.

Comment: no, it fails with the same constraint error error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lazy_product_stock_comb_idx2"